# Mouse click inside cube not working

Tags: html, css, 3d

The mouse is working for the `.wrap`, `.cube` and `.front`, but not for `.left`, `.right`, `.top`, `.bottom` and `.back`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="cube">
        <div class="front">front</div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="video-wrapper" data-min-width="125" data-width="0.6">
                    <iframe data-aspect-ratio="16:9" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PnwEkeSed5Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h4>Video 1</h4>
                    <p>
                        Cortado at cultivar irish, trifecta roast that whipped spoon lungo aftertaste. Et eu, single origin, cappuccino beans, kopi-luwak grinder ristretto aromatic extra. At robust mazagran, in lungo cultivar aromatic irish. Id as decaffeinated lungo steamed
                        medium cream filter americano. Cortado at cultivar irish, trifecta roast that whipped spoon lungo aftertaste. Et eu, single origin, cappuccino beans, kopi-luwak grinder ristretto aromatic extra. At robust mazagran, in lungo cultivar
                        aromatic irish. Id as decaffeinated lungo steamed medium cream filter americano.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
        </div>
        <div class="top">
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="video-wrapper" data-min-width="125" data-width="0.6">
                    <iframe data-aspect-ratio="16:9" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PnwEkeSed5Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h4>Video 1</h4>
                    <p>
                        Cortado at cultivar irish, trifecta roast that whipped spoon lungo aftertaste. Et eu, single origin, cappuccino beans, kopi-luwak grinder ristretto aromatic extra. At robust mazagran, in lungo cultivar aromatic irish. Id as decaffeinated lungo steamed
                        medium cream filter americano. Cortado at cultivar irish, trifecta roast that whipped spoon lungo aftertaste. Et eu, single origin, cappuccino beans, kopi-luwak grinder ristretto aromatic extra. At robust mazagran, in lungo cultivar
                        aromatic irish. Id as decaffeinated lungo steamed medium cream filter americano.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <iframe data-aspect-ratio="16:9" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PnwEkeSed5Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <h4>Theorie</h4>
            <p>
                Cortado at cultivar irish, trifecta roast that whipped spoon lungo aftertaste. Et eu, single origin, cappuccino beans, kopi-luwak grinder ristretto aromatic extra. At robust mazagran, in lungo cultivar aromatic irish. Id as decaffeinated lungo steamed
                medium cream filter americano. Cortado at cultivar irish, trifecta roast that whipped spoon lungo aftertaste. Et eu, single origin, cappuccino beans, kopi-luwak grinder ristretto aromatic extra. At robust mazagran, in lungo cultivar aromatic
                irish. Id as decaffeinated lungo steamed medium cream filter americano.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
    perspective: 600px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cube {
    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.cube > div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.cube > div:not(.front) {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: lightgrey;
}

.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(400px);
    //transform:  translateZ(400px);
}

.left {
    transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-400px);
    transform-origin: left center;
}

.right {
    transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(400px);
    transform-origin: right top;
}

.bottom {
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(10px);
    transform-origin: center bottom;
}

.top {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(30px);
    transform-origin: left top;
}

.front {
    transform: translateZ(100px);
}

.content {
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.content > div {
    float: left;
}

.content > .video-wrapper {
    line-height: 100%;
}

.content > .text {
    width: 35%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}

.only-video {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}

.only-video iframe {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}
```

What can be done to make the mouse click work inside the cube?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwcza5rb/)

Comment: set pointer-events: none; in .front, it is masking the others

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

.back becomes clickable (at least in FF) when you remove width and height from .cube > div

Restore .back styling:

```
.back {height: 100%;}
```

and maybe this will work for the other elements too, ie. set only required width or height within their own selector.

EDIT: pointer-events suggested by vals is a much better approach.